# Highcharts - choosing the legend size

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to change the size of my legend on a highchart pie.

There are previous subjects about that but I guess their solutions aren't working with my versions of softwares.

Here is my interactive code : http://jsfiddle.net/qt9h4zuc/2/

```
$(function() {           
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        ...
});
);
```

Does someone have an idea to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it ! 
Just add this line in plotOption

```
style: { fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif', lineHeight: '18px', fontSize: '25px' }
```

In the end we'll have :

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            size:'60%',
            fontSize:'30pt',
            dataLabels: {
                color:'red',
                enabled: true,
        style: { fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif', lineHeight: '18px', fontSize: '25px' }


            }
        }
    },
```

Cheers !